# Line/string manipulation

Tags: regex, bash, perl, awk, sed

I have been tremendously helped/taught by the community here many times when it comes to regex/perl/string manipulation. Here's the text:

```
===================================
| IO Statistics                   |
|                                 |
| Interval size: 2.254 secs (dur) |
| Col 1: Frames and bytes         |
|---------------------------------|
|                |1               |
| Interval       | Frames | Bytes |
|---------------------------------|
| 0.000 <> 2.254 |     10 |  1709 |
===================================
```

What I want:

```
Time: 2.254 Seconds
Frames: 10
Bytes: 1709
```

Any help? Thanks!!!

Comment: What have you tried?  I see some options, but seeing your existing attempts will help us guide you to a solution that you understand the best.

Comment: I had tried a combination of `sed` and `awk` commands to pipe the text through, nothing quite like paxdiablo's answer though! Still expanding my skills to include regex/string manip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that *specific* text, you can use:

```
 pax> awk '
 ...>   $6=="(dur)" {print "Time: "$4" Seconds"}
 ...>   $3=="<>"    {print "Frames: "$6"\nBytes: "$8}' inFile

Time: 2.254 Seconds
Frames: 10
Bytes: 1709
```

That's getting the duration from the `Interval size` line and the other two figures from the line containing `<>`.

If your requirements are more complex than that, you'll need to spell them out. For example, let's say you want to get the information from the `<>` lines from the following (slightly modified) file:

```
pax> cat infile
===================================
| IO Statistics                   |
|                                 |
| Interval size: 5.000 secs (dur) |
| Col 1: Frames and bytes         |
|---------------------------------|
|                |1               |
| Interval       | Frames | Bytes |
|---------------------------------|
| 0.000 <> 1.234 |     10 |  1234 |
| 1.234 <> 2.718 |     20 |  9876 |
| 2.718 <> 3.142 |     42 |    42 |
| 3.142 <> 5.000 |     99 |    97 |
===================================
```

You could then use something like:

```
pax> awk '
...>   $3=="<>" {
...>     print "Time: "($4-$2)" Seconds";
...>     print "Frames: "$6"";
...>     print "Bytes: "$8"\n"
...>   }' inFile

Time: 1.234 Seconds
Frames: 10
Bytes: 1234

Time: 1.484 Seconds
Frames: 20
Bytes: 9876

Time: 0.424 Seconds
Frames: 42
Bytes: 42

Time: 1.858 Seconds
Frames: 99
Bytes: 97
```

Answer (score 1):

Kind of ambiguous as to what to do with other inputs, but in perl (on the command-line as a ~one-liner):

```
#| 0.000 <> 2.254 |     10 |  1709 |
perl -ie '
if (m:^\|\s+(\d+\.\d+)\s+<>\s+(\d+\.\d+)\s+\|\s+(\d+)\s+\|\s+(\d+)\s+\|:){
  print "Time: ".($2-$1)." Seconds\nFrames: $3\nBytes: $4\n\n"
}' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

A pragmatic solution:

```
tail -n 2 file |
  awk '{ printf "Time: %s seconds\nFrames: %s\nBytes: %s\n", $4, $6, $8; exit }'
```

- Assumes that the line of interest is the second-to-last input line.
- Extracts the 4th, 6th and 8th field from that line and formats the output with `printf`.